# Is there any function or way to merge multiple row data into one row using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pydantic

This is my input data `df`. I have tried to combine fifth row with fourth row as it is relates to the forth row.

```py
0   Date & Time\nValue Date Description                Reference No.    Debit       Credit  Balance
1   01/12/2022              01/12/2022\n125437                          74,000.00   0.00    34,984,307.42
2   08:35:27                MCM InhouseTrf KE TARMIN                
3   01/12/2022              01/12/2022\n125437                          650,000.00  0.00    34,334,307.42
4   08:35:28                MCM InhouseTrf KE UTAMA RADAR               
5                           CAHAYA              
6   01/12/2022              01/12/2022\n125437                          20,000.00   0.00    34,314,307.42
7   08:35:29                MCM InhouseTrf KE UTAMA RADAR               
8                           CAHAYA
```

I have tried to extract the data using this code.

```py
df2=df[(df[3]=='') & (df[4]=='') & (df[5]=='')]
print(df2)
```

```py
  0                               1 2 3 4 5
2  08:35:27       MCM InhouseTrf  KE TARMIN        
4  08:35:28  MCM InhouseTrf  KE UTAMA RADAR        
5                                    CAHAYA        
7  08:35:29  MCM InhouseTrf  KE UTAMA RADAR        
8                                    CAHAYA
```

Expected Output:

```py
0   Date & Time\nValue Date Description                                             Ref No.    Debit       Credit  Balance
1   01/12/2022 08:35:27     01/12/2022\n125437 MCM InhouseTrf KE TARMIN                        74,000.00   0.00    34,984,307.42
2   01/12/2022 08:35:28     01/12/2022\n125437 MCM InhouseTrf KE UTAMA RADAR CAHAYA            650,000.00  0.00    34,334,307.42 
3   01/12/2022 08:35:29     01/12/2022\n125437 MCM InhouseTrf KE UTAMA RADAR CAHAYA            20,000.00   0.00    34,314,307.42
```

Please advice on more pythonic way or pydantic/pandas way.
You can reproduce the input data

```py
data = {
    "Date & Time\nValue Date": [
        "01/12/2022", "08:35:27", "01/12/2022", "08:35:28", "", "01/12/2022", "08:35:29", "",
    ],
    "Description": [
        "", "MCM InhouseTrf KE TARMIN", "", "MCM InhouseTrf KE UTAMA RADAR", "CAHAYA", "", "MCM InhouseTrf KE UTAMA RADAR", "CAHAYA",
    ],
    "Reference No.": [
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
    ],
    "Debit": [
        "74,000.00", "", "650,000.00", "", "", "20,000.00", "", "",
    ],
    "Credit": [
        "0.00", "", "0.00", "", "", "0.00", "", "",
    ],
    "Balance": [
        "34,984,307.42", "", "34,334,307.42", "", "", "34,314,307.42", "", "",
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Please check. reproducible example of the data code segment is added.

Answer (score 4):

Create groups by comapre e.g. `Debit` with cumulative sum and aggragate `join` and `first`:

```
df = df.groupby(df['Debit'].ne('').cumsum()).agg({'Date & Time\nValue Date':' '.join,
                                                  'Description':' '.join,
                                                  'Reference No.':'first',
                                                  'Debit':'first',
                                                  'Credit':'first',
                                                  'Balance':'first'})
print (df)
      Date & Time\nValue Date                            Description  \
Debit                                                                  
1         01/12/2022 08:35:27               MCM InhouseTrf KE TARMIN   
2        01/12/2022 08:35:28    MCM InhouseTrf KE UTAMA RADAR CAHAYA   
3        01/12/2022 08:35:29    MCM InhouseTrf KE UTAMA RADAR CAHAYA   

      Reference No.       Debit Credit        Balance  
Debit                                                  
1                     74,000.00   0.00  34,984,307.42  
2                    650,000.00   0.00  34,334,307.42  
3                     20,000.00   0.00  34,314,307.42
```